# Adding items to column in Sencha Architect 4

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-architect

Code in Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/281k

How to reproduce this code in Sencha Architect 4?

More precisely, how to **add items to column**? I found items only in **Action columns**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to add custom property to the column. Steps:

1. Add Grid panel
2. Add simple grid column
3. Select the column, in the filter of configs, write `items` and click ADD button
4. Now just find this new config and edit it

Here it's explained in tutorial https://youtu.be/2wTAdPaG2Xk?t=414, I highly recommend watching whole video, there are some cool tricks.

[image: sencha architect column]